# inline embed sample xml

Tags: xml, jquery

Hello I'm a noob and practicing getting XML and parsing it.

The problem is that I think I am thinking too much in "JSON".

Can anyone show me how to make it work? Thanks.

**http://jsfiddle.net/NJMyD/1066/**

```
var xmlString = "<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>';

var myXmlData = $.parseXML(xmlString);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(myXmlData, function() {
        $('<li>' + this.from + '</li>').appendTo("#groups");
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post the code you have problems with, rather than links.  Explain what is wrong with it, including any error messages from the browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not parsing your `XML` variable correctly. Here is the Solution for fiddle 1:

```
var xmlString = "<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>";

var myXmlData = $.parseXML(xmlString),
$xml = $(myXmlData),
$title = $xml.find( "from" );
 $.each($xml, function(index) {
   $('<li>' + $title.text() + '</li>').appendTo("#groups");
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/NJMyD/1069/